# How can i apply z-index to pseudo elements

Tags: css

How it looks when i resize

[image]

I have tried to applied z-indexs but dont work.

https://

jsfiddle

.net

/Ilug/

jnqeLoc8

/10/

Sorry i tried to write the link and i cant so i copy seperatly.

Comment: I think you need to set overflow:hidden to the lines not sure. Please provide Fiddle example for better understanding

Comment: Provide some code please

Comment: I have paste the link to jsfiddle please check.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it's hard to answer this, but based on your screenshot, try adding a background color of white (`#fff`) in the pseudo element style block.

If you can create a demo on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), then you'll get better answers.

Comment: I have paste the link to jsfiddle please check.

Comment: Add white background color on `.navActive1` and `.nav2`, then instead of having a pseudo element on each step, put it on the main container, like so:

`.conNav::before { content: ""; width: 100%; height: 5px; background-color: lightgray; position: absolute; top: 25px; z-index: -1; transform: translateZ(-1px); }` You may need to adjust the width of the container.

Comment: but the circles have to change color and size when i click on thems and the lines next to the cirlces have to change bgColor to red